# Submitting 2 forms asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, asynchronous

I am trying to submit 2 forms with one click.  It even looks like both forms are being submitted but the call to the second form (from the callback on the first form post) has no tangible results.
Here is the javascript:
N.B. the first function is in the recruitment_module

```
this.submit_form = function()
{
  if( check_field_input())
    {                   
    var fname = $('#rec_first_name').val();
    var lname = $('#rec_last_name').val();
    var usr_email = $('#rec_email').val();
    var id = $('input[name="params_id"]').val();
    var x_id = $('input[name="XID"]').val();
    var url = $('#recruitment').attr('action');
    var mainformUrl = $('#recruitmentform').attr('action');

    var poster = $.post( url, {params_id: id, XID: x_id, firstname: fname, lastname: lname,  email: usr_email},
      function(response){
        if (response.success == true) {
            $.post( mainformUrl, $('form#recruitmentform').serialize());
            return true;
            //$('form#recruitmentform').submit();
            } else {
              alert("Error: " + response.errors[0]);
            }
        });
    }
} 

$(document).ready(function () { 
        var rec_mod = new recruitment_module();
        $('#submit_btn').click( function() { return rec_mod.submit_form(); });
    });
```

On debugging the script I can see that it does indeed make it to the call to post the second form using the serialize function but the page is not posted.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can't really debug this without runnable code that we could examine and modify.  Here are the steps to debug something like this:

1. Make sure `mainformUrl` is in the same domain as your page so you aren't being blocked by same-origin security restrictions.
2. Check the error console or debug console for any errors.
3. Add both a success handler and an error handler to your ajax call and see which gets called and what it says.